Can not get it working on main net
I have created a program and launched it on devnet, testnet and now mainnet. Have created a frontend that works great on devnet. But now when I have launched it on Mainnet tried it on mulitple diffrent cluster also change WalletAdapterNetwork.Mainnet
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I get this constantly and have had this problem for one week, tried to launch the program mulitple times. SO when I try to interact with the program i get this error.
          .initialize()
          .accounts({
            playerAccount: playerPDA,
            player: publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
          })
          .transaction();

        const transactionSignature = await sendTransaction(tx, connection); ```

what is find wierd is that it works great on devnet? does anyone have a clue?



  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/IxUAacZW.png


You need a different RPC endpoint. The one you're using is not meant for production workloads and is has heavy limitations. More info on RPCs here https://solana.com/rpc

Hello! :-)
But I have bought a dedicated RPC endpoint on Helius but still I get this error?

It did work, you were totally right, it was the issue that it was not dedicated to the wallet adapter, thank you
